# How to use function overload with classes in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Given following TypeScript code

```
class NumberChecker { }
class StringChecker { }
class Component {}
class ComponentChecker { }
class Grid { }
class GridChecker { }

function check(element: number): NumberChecker;
function check(element: string): StringChecker;
function check(element: Grid): GridChecker;
function check(element: Component): ComponentChecker {
    if (typeof element === 'number') {
        return new NumberChecker();
    }
    if (typeof element === 'string') {
        return new StringChecker();
    }
    if (element instanceof Component) {
        return new ComponentChecker();
    }
    if (element instanceof Grid) {
        return new GridChecker();
    }
}

const a = check(2); // a is NumberChecker
const b = check('sdf'); // b is StringChecker
const c = check(new Component()); // c is GridChecker
const d = check(new Grid()); // d is GridChecker
```

Why `c` and `d` are both `GridChecker`? I was expecting `c` to be `ComponentChecker`.

[Link to Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20NumberChecker%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20StringChecker%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Component%20%7B%7D%0D%0Aclass%20ComponentChecker%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Grid%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20GridChecker%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20check(element%3A%20number)%3A%20NumberChecker%3B%0D%0Afunction%20check(element%3A%20string)%3A%20StringChecker%3B%0D%0Afunction%20check(element%3A%20Grid)%3A%20GridChecker%3B%0D%0Afunction%20check(element%3A%20Component)%3A%20ComponentChecker%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20element%20%3D%3D%3D%20'number')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20NumberChecker()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20element%20%3D%3D%3D%20'string')%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20StringChecker()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(element%20instanceof%20Component)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ComponentChecker()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(element%20instanceof%20Grid)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20GridChecker()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20check(2)%3B%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20check('sdf')%3B%0D%0Aconst%20c%20%3D%20check(new%20Component())%3B%0D%0Aconst%20d%20%3D%20check(new%20Grid())%3B)

Comment: You should try that again with different definitions. Those `Component ` and `Grid` are currently compatible.

Comment: Just tried adding different properties to both classes and got compilation error 'Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.' which I don't know how to solve.

Comment: But that's a good point. Each `Checker` class will have different methods. If I try to add them, I get even more compilation errors. I though that return types didn't have to be compatible between each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the actual implementation needs to cover **all** of the options, in your case, it should be:

```
function check(element: number): NumberChecker;
function check(element: string): StringChecker;
function check(element: Grid): GridChecker;
function check(element: Component): ComponentChecker;
function check(element: number | string | Grid | Component) {
    // ...
}
```

Then the type for:

```
const c = check(new Component());
```

Is `ComponentChecker`.

But again, only if the different classes don't have the same structure.